# Which correlation analysis is appropriate for binary and ordinal variables?

Tags: matlab, likert, psychometrics, binary-data, agreement-statistics

Violin players were asked to rate 5 violins from least to most rich on a `[0 1]`, `0.05-increment` scale, `most always = 1` and `least always = 0`. They were then asked to set a "limit of acceptability," i.e., to set a point along the scale above which violins are considered acceptable in terms of richness. By setting `acceptable = 1` and `not acceptable = 0`, a binary variable is obtained for each player, in addition to their rating. So, as an example, for a player I have the variables `rating = [0.3 0.45 0 1 0.85]` and for a `limit = 0.45`, `acc = [0 1 0 1 1]`. I use Lin's concordance correlation coefficient to explore consistency within and between individuals for the case of ratings. However, this is not possible for the "acceptable" variable: when a player sets their `limit = 0`, then `acc = [1 1 1 1 1]` and hence the presence of zero variance becomes an issue. I am trying to figure out a good, interesting way to analyze the binary data, perhaps compare consistency in ratings with consistency in acceptability limits, or more in-depth relations between the two variables. I am not very experienced in statistics, so any suggestions and ideas are welcome. I primarily work with MATLAB.

Comment: Although you list some goals, I am still not really clear what the point of your study is. Is this just initial-phase exploratory work? Are you trying to test some hypothesis taken from a theory? What would the "consistency" of their ratings mean? Are they rating the same violins more than once? For research like this, you may want to look into [psychometrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychometrics), a discipline related to statistics; I added the psychometrics tag to your Q.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My primary question is how consistent are players (within and between individuals) in evaluating violins (in terms of overall quality or certain attributes), ie I'm investigating the reliability and reproducibility of their evaluations. For this study, the participants rated the same set of violins in 6 conditions, each condition involving 3 repetitions (trials). At the end of each rating they had to provide a limit of acceptability from 0 (all violins) to 1 (only the highest-rated one). I am interested in potential differences between ratings and limits.

Comment: Thanks, that information is actually vital to providing any decent answer to your question.